# Is every print of Shree Bhagavad-Gita the authentic one?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Shree Bhagavad-Gita  is available in different prints or Versions (according to different authors) in the  market. Which one is most authentic one , according with meaning and how one should select the right print for oneself?

Comment: Translations without commentary are generally same everywhere... although it also differs... commentary greatly differs as per philosophy... if you subscribe to Advaita philosophy you can read Bhagvad Gita with Adi Shankara commentary... if you subscribe to Vishnu Vishishtadvaita you can read with Ramanuja commentary... if Dvaita philosophy then Madhavacharya commentary... if ISKCON / Gaudiya then Prabhupada Commentary... However one can read Bhagvad Gita without commentaries also...

Comment: With regard to ISKCON/Prabhupada version, I always found it curious that the book is called "Bhagavad Gita As It Is." The problem with this title is that the book is obviously NOT the Bhagavad Gita AS IT IS. If it were such in the true sense, the book would only consist of the Sanskrit text. However, about 90% of the book is the translator's English translation of the Sanskrit and his voluminous commentary. A more appropriate and fitting title would be "Bhagavad Gita According to Me." Just something to keep in mind as you explore the various versions...

Comment: Every translation is more or less good, although there could be differences in their quality. However great differences are with interpretations of the Bhagavad gita teachings in the commentaries. There some interpretations may sound more convincing, while the other are not so convincing as true. When you analyze translations and especially interpretations of the commentators you will see which are more convincing to you, and which are not convincing. Thus those who are more convincing to you are "the right one" :) ...But if you're a neophyte in Hindu dharma you'll not be able to see all that.

Comment: Refere IIT-Kharagpur's website for collection of translations & commentaries: http://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/. In my experience, Swami Gambhirananda's translations are closest to Sanskrit. They don't subscribe to any methodology, but very much focused to pure translations.

Answer (score 2):

Currently we have number of commentaries on Bhagavad-Geeta available. Some of them even written by atheists may be. We might then wonder which commentary to read; as it may not be possible for everyone of us to understand the sublime message directly without commentary.

In Geeta this question is addressed by Krishna. krishna in 4th chapter says:

> This supreme science was thus received through the chain of disciplic
>   succession, and the saintly kings understood it in that way. But in
>   course of time the succession was broken, and therefore the science as
>   it is appears to be lost.

"**Disciplic Succession**" is a very important word here. The Acharya(Spiritual master) passes down the message of God without unnecessarily incorporating his own whims. So if we can trace the disciplic succession of the commentator back to Krishna then the commentary may be taken as authentic.

Basically different Acharyas have written commentary from the viewpoint of their philosophy. Ex **Adi Shankara**'s Commentary explains the message of Godhead from standpoint of **Advaita(Non-duality)**

Similarly(Following are Vaishnava philosophies):

**Ramanujacharya:Vishishta-Advaita**

**Nibarka-Acharya:Dvaitadvaita**

**Vallabhacharya:Shuddha advaita**

**Madhvacharya:Dvaita(duality)**

**[ISKCON Commentary by Srila Prabhupada](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg) : Achintya-Beda-abheda(Inconcievable simultaneous oneness and duality).**

Above mentioned are the commentaries by Acharyas that are connected to Krishna through disciplic succession.

More about Vaishnava Sampradaya(disciplic successions) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampradaya).